# Remove non-unique string components from a column in R

Tags: r

```
example <- data.frame(
  file_name = c("some_file_name_first_2020.csv", 
                "some_file_name_second_and_third_2020.csv",
                "some_file_name_4_2020_update.csv"),
  a = 1:3
)
```

```
example
#>                                  file_name a
#> 1            some_file_name_first_2020.csv 1
#> 2 some_file_name_second_and_third_2020.csv 2
#> 3         some_file_name_4_2020_update.csv 3
```

I have a dataframe that looks something like this example. The "some_file_name" part changes often and the unique identifier is usually in the middle and there can be suffixed information (sometimes) that is important to retain.

I would like to end up with the dataframe below. The approach I can think of is finding all common string "components" and removing them from each row.

```
desired
#>          file_name a
#> 1            first 1
#> 2 second_and_third 2
#> 3         4_update 3
```

Comment: So you would like to erase any "components" that occurs more than once?

Comment: Yes, or remove components that occur in every row. Either would be acceptable. Sorry I don't know a better word than "component" to describe what I want.

Comment: Just to understand, the "some_file_name" part occurs in every row?

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is part of something I will be doing every week and week-by-week the "some_file_name" will change for each dataframe, but within a dataframe that will be constant.

Comment: Do you have access at the logic with which the names are generated?

Comment: Exactly, you need to look for a pattern. If you can give us that, we can help you. Without a pattern that distinguishes some_file:name from the suffix it would be close to magic to find a solution.

Comment: File names are "handwritten" by a human being - they are 99% consistent within a set of files but vary drastically between different sets of files. Understand there may not be a solution - appreciate the thought you guys put in nevertheless. I'll update if I end up using anything generalizable that others may find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the example shared, perhaps you can use this to make a more general solution :

```
#split the data on "_" or "."
list_data <- strsplit(example$file_name, '_|\\.')
#Get the words that occur only once
unique_words <- names(Filter(function(x) x==1,  table(unlist(list_data))))
#Keep only unique_words and paste the string back.
sapply(list_data, function(x) paste(x[x %in% unique_words], collapse = "_"))

#[1] "first"            "second_and_third" "4_update"
```

However, this answer relies on the fact that you would have separators like `"_"` in the filenames to detect each "component".

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. I'm thinking I can use stringr::str_replace_all to replace any seperator-like characters with "_". Thank you again.